# Lipschitz solution using Method of Characteristics PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Use the method of characteristics to solve the problem
$$ 
u_t+ u u_x = 0  
$$
with initial data
$$
  u(0,x) = \begin{cases} 1& x < 0 \\ 1- x & x \in [0,1] \\ 0 &  x >1 .   
\end{cases}
 $$
What is the time interval where a Lipschitz solution exists ?

> I have thus far the following: Consider the coefficients of each partial derivative, i.e. let:
> $$
> \frac{dt}{ds} = 1 \qquad \frac{dx}{ds} = z \qquad \frac{dz}{ds} = 0$$
> With the following conditions:
> $$ t(r,0) = 0 \qquad x(r,0) = r
>  \qquad  z(r,0) =\begin{cases} 1& r < 0 \\ 1- r & x \in [0,1] \\ 0 &  r >1 .   
> \end{cases}$$

> First integration will give us:

$$t = s + c_1 \qquad z = c_2 \qquad \frac{dx}{ds} = c_2$$

> Now since $t(r,0) = c_1 = 0$, we get that $t = s$. Hence $x = c_2(r)s + c_3(r) = c_2(r)t + c_3(r)$. So suppose the general form of this solution is $F(x-ut)$. Now the particular solution with regards to the initial condition, $u(x,0) = F(x)$, Hence the solution would be:

> \begin{cases}
>         1 & \qquad  x-ut < 0
>            \cr
>           1- (x-ut) & \qquad (x-ut) \in [0,1]
>                \cr
>             0 &  \qquad (x-ut) >1 .   
> \end{cases}
> \begin{cases}
>         1 & \qquad  x < t
>            \cr
>           1- x+ ut & \qquad (x-ut) \in [0,1]
>                \cr
>             0 &  \qquad x >1. \end{cases}

What am doing right or wrong? Is the solution I have Lipschitz?

Comment: You need [begin{cases}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex)

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2473812/418542) (same problem) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202407/418542) (similar use of the method of characteristics)