# Rankine Hugoniot condition for non-scalar initial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Going off the example the following question ([The Rankine-Hugoniot condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473812/the-rankine-hugoniot-condition)), how do we calculate the Rankine Hugoniot condition for nonscalar initial data? For $t \leq 1$ I understand how the author obtains the piecewise solution, but I am unclear how he obtains the bounds for each solution. Would anyone be able to explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of systems of conservation laws
$$
\boldsymbol{u}_t + \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{u})_x = \boldsymbol{0}
$$
where bold characters are vectors (it works also in the scalar case),
the Rankine-Hugoniot condition (RH) for shock waves of speed $s$ is obtained by writing the scalar RH condition for each entry, i.e.
$$
[\! [ \boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{u}) ]\!] = s [\! [ \boldsymbol{u} ]\!] .
$$
If $\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{u}) = \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{b}$ is [linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3933353), we end up with the eigenvalue problem
$$
\boldsymbol{A} [\! [ \boldsymbol{u} ]\!] = s [\! [ \boldsymbol{u} ]\!] .
$$
(The other query was answered directly in the comments of OP's linked post)